# Nginx redirect with PATH parameters

Tags: nginx, redirect, parameters

I need to redirect pages from the old URL to the new one. My problem is that I can't figure out how to rewrite the URL using the parameters from the old path in the new path.
Old url:

```
section/{section_id}/author/{author_id}/books/{book_id}
```

Need to redirect to:

```
library/books/{book_id}?sectionId={section_id}&authorId={author_id}
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/section/([^/]+)/author/([^/]+)/books/([^/]+)$ /library/books/$3?sectionId=$1&authorId=$2 redirect;`

Comment: Thanks, almost done! there is one problem left, that the question mark in front of the query string does not want to be written in the URL, it turns out like this: library/books/{book_id}sectionId={section_id}&authorId={author_id}